# how to map processor to dto

Tags: java, mapping, entity, dto

I am building a MealPlanner application which builds up a menu of meals based on user preferences, and I need some guidance to set 2 fields in DTO (field names: preferenceType, resultState).

Structure of Entity (named Meal):

```
class Meal {
    String itemName; //Such as Pizza, Sandwich
    double portion; //such as 1.5
    double cost; //such as 15.5, default currency is dollars
}
```

Structure of DTO:

```
class MealDTO {

    //Identical to Meal
    String itemName;
    double portion;
    double cost;

    //Additional fields in DTO
    String preferenceType; //FAT FREE, DAIRY FREE, VEGETARIAN
    String resultState; //OPTIMAL, FEASIBLE, INFEASIBLE
}
```

**Class to map values between the two classes:**

```
public class FieldsMapper {

    // MealDTO -> Meal
    public Meal MealDtoToMeal(MealDTO mealDto) {
        Meal meal = new Meal();
        meal.setItemName(mealDto.getItemName());
        return meal;
    }

    //Meal -> MealDTO
    public MealDTO MealToMealDto(Meal meal) {
        MealDTO mealDto = new MealDTO();
        mealDto.setItemName(meal.getItemName());
        mealDto.setPortion(meal.getPortion());
        mealDto.setCost(meal.getCost());
        return mealDto;
    }
}
```

[Please click here: MealPlanner full flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbfHh.png)

This way, the values of preferenceType and cost are lost.
**How do I map preferenceType, resultState to the DTO?**

(NOTE: Meal Planner flow as steps

1. Map user request(contains only itemName) to MealDTO (other fields except itemName are empty).
2. Map MealDTO to Meal using FieldsMapper.
3. Pass Meal to third party, black box logic. This logic will return a map with the structure {<portion, 2>, <cost, 14>, <preferenceType, VEGETARIAN>, <resultState, OPTIMAL> }
4. The portion and cost are mapped to Meal entity fields portion, cost.
5. Map Meal to MealDTO and return the DTO object.)

Comment: If the `portion` in your `Meal` is going to have decimal values, it should not be of data type `int`. Please consider correcting that.

Comment: you did not show us how are you using the MapStruct, we do not know how you really map these 2 objects, consider adding more code

Comment: @hocikto, Mapstruct uses getters and setters to map the fields. To avoid any confusion I have replaced it with a custom class FieldsMapper. Question and diagram has been updated.

Comment: well looks simple.. be sure that the object that holds the values from the blackbox have are really set there (either by debugging or simple printing out the object to console) and then check the variable where you call mapper.MealToMealDto(meal) maybe you assign it somewhere wrongfully.. can you show us the code where you call the mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should use enums instead of String for your resultState and preferenceType fields as they have fixed values.

What I think you should do is create another DTO which contains the MealDTO and the resultState and preferenceType fields e.g UserMealDTO. So something like:

```java
class UserMealDTO {
    MealDTO meal;
    MealPreference preferenceType;
    ResultState resultState; 
}

// Enums 

public enum MealPreference {
    FAT FREE, DAIRY FREE, VEGETARIAN;
}

public enum ResultState {
    OPTIMAL, FEASIBLE, INFEASIBLE;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Amer, how do I set the fields preferenceType, resultState? Is userMealDTO.setPreferenceType() and userMealDTO.setResultState() the only way? Is there a more elegant way to do it? I am calling the third party jar from a processor class.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the setters of UserMealDTO to set the values. I am not sure what you mean by elegant. What I am suggesting is simply have another layer of abstraction over your Meal to give you the control you require.

Comment: well of course you can have 2 constructors for the object to provide more control, one private with no arguments and one public with the arguments that are always required for the object to be set, something like public MealDto(String prefType, String resultState) { Objects.requireNonNull(prefType) } or additionaly check if string is empty

Comment: Thankyou hockito, I think constructors are the way to go.